# Android NDK, compliling shared objects

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am currently trying to use Android NDK and am following a tutorial. One of the steps (Step 3: Compile the shared Objects) I do not get how to do. Frankly, I don't get what it is. Could someone explain to me what to do? Thanks in advance.

https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Shared objects" is the Unixy term for dynamic libraries. That's the form that compiled NDK code takes. To build those for your project:

- Run Cygwin
- Change directory to the `jni` folder in your project
- Run the command `ndk-build` from the NDK folder

Comment: All I am getting is the Cygwin Terminal Window, do I change the directory from within the folder? Or is there a separate Cygwin program I have to run?

Comment: You type the following command: `cd /cygdrive/c/my-project-path/jni` and press Enter. Use the / character as the path separator; such is the Unixy way. Same goes for the `ndk-build` thing, except the path should point into the NDK folder.

Comment: So I put this in cd/cygdrive/c/C:/Development/Android/vuforia-sdk-android-1-5-9/samples/ImageTargets/jni   and it says it can't find it... sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Change to `cd /cygdrive/c/Development/Android/vuforia-sdk-android-1-5-9/samples/ImageTarg‌ets/jni` . The `/cygdrive/c` is the Cygwin's way of saying `C:`. Also, a space between a command and its argument is generally beneficial.